# Create nested tree Object from a flat string Array

Tags: javascript, recursion

Given the following Array of strings:

```js
['A','AA','AAA','AAAA']
```

I am trying to convert them to an object like this using a function:

```js
{
  name: 'A',
  children: [
    {
      name: 'AA',
      children: [
        {
          name: 'AAA',
          children: [
            {
              name: 'AAAA'
              children: []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I cannot find a solution that works with recursivity. Any suggestions please?

What i've tried, and it's not working since it's lacking recursivity logic:

```
array = ['A','AA','AAA','AAAA']

foo(array) {
  let resultArray = []
  while (array.length > 0) {
      const item = array.shift()
      
      resultArray.push({
        name: item,
        children: array[0]
      })
    }
  return resultArray
}

console.log(foo(array))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add a [mcve] of that effort

Comment: Hello, added my try. It's not working it's just an idea

Comment: Your attempt is not a recursive function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduceRight`:

```js
let result = ['A','AA','AAA','AAAA'].reduceRight(
    (children, name) => [{ name, children }], []
).pop(); 
      
console.log(result);
```

It is a bit of an odd structure, as the children array never has more than one element in it...